# What kind of parameters can be automatically moved in return statements?

Tags: c++, c++11

Andrew Koenig wrote an article with the title [Some Optimizations Are More Important Than Others](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/some-optimizations-are-more-important-th/240159684) containing the following two function definitions:

```
string rev(string s) {
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s; // GCC-4.8 uses move constructor
}

string rev(string&& s) {
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s; // GCC-4.8 uses copy constructor
}
```

The article implies that the second function (in combination with a `const string&` overload) is more efficient than the first one. However, that's not what I am seeing, when I test it with GCC-4.8. The first function *moves* the object `s` in the `return` statement whereas the second function *copies* the object. If I change the return statement in the second function to `return move(s);`, then the object will be *moved* in both cases.

**Question:** What kind of parameters can be automatically *moved* in `return` statements? And more specificially, can parameters declared as non-const rvalue-references be automatically *moved*?

Comment: "*However, that's not what I am seeing, when I test it with GCC-4.8.*" How are you testing the efficiency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only things that can be automatically moved via a return statement are variables that:

1. Are automatic variables.
2. Are declared in the scope of the function, such that they are guaranteed to be destroyed upon the function's exiting.
3. Are variables of value types.

#3 eliminates references of any kind. If you want to move from a reference, you have to explicitly say to move from it.

However, if you're wondering why the latter would be more efficient, it has to do with the number of moves.

In the first case, you have a copy/move *into* the function parameter `s`. The user must copy or move some string into the parameter. And then the parameter's data gets moved back out.

In the second case, you have neither a copy nor a move into the function parameter; it just references an existing object. If the user calls the rvalue reference version, you have a single copy that goes *out* of the parameter.

So the first case has one copy/move and one move, vs. exactly one copy. So if the user is copying the parameter in, your first case will be slower thanks to an extra move.

Movement is not free. It may be *cheap* (relative to copying), but it's not *free.* 2 moves are more expensive than 1. And if the user calls the `const&` version, that means they asked to copy the string. So they get a copy followed by a move that will almost certainly be elided.

Personally, I would weigh the minor efficiency gain against the significant headache of implementing the same function twice. In some cases, it might be worth it. But I wouldn't do it as a matter of course.

Comment: Thanks. The question was really only about automatic move operations on parameters. If I understand you correctly, the second function is worse than the first, if `std::move` is not used in the `return` statement. Can you add the reference to the C++ standard where the above rules come from?